Proof that everything dissolves in Lord Krishna
Where in the shastras is it written that everything, including mūla prakritī dissolves into Lord Krishna?

This verse is a declaration by Krishna Himself of the fact that all dissolves into him:

BG 7.6: Know that all living beings are manifested by these two energies of Mine. I am the source of the entire creation, and into Me it again dissolves.

Which I hope conclusively answers your questions.


The worlds owe their origin to Krishna and in him are they dissolved.
It is in Krishna that all the beings of this universe are established.


260 (35), Arghabhiharana Parva, Mahabharata.


O Madhusudana! You gather up all beings at the end of a yuga. O
scorcher of enemies! You withdraw the entire universe into yourself
and remain alone.


310 (13), Kairata Parva, Mahabharata.

